# Read ordered Data Yet unstructured data is accumulated

Tags: python, csv

new to python here so your help is really appreciated, i've created a function which reads a csv  file and stores the items to a dictionary, the items in the csv file is already sorted, my goal was to just append the list in order as is without calling any sort function in python. You can see that the items read are in order below.

this is the output

```
{'term': 'arsen', 'docID': '1000'}
1000
arsen
{'term': 'exchang', 'docID': '1000'}
1000
exchang
{'term': 'one', 'docID': '1000'}
1000
one
{'term': 'share', 'docID': '1000'}
1000
share
{'term': 'via', 'docID': '1000'}
1000
via
dictemplist:
{'exchang': '1000', 'share': '1000', 'via': '1000', 'arsen': '1000', 'one': '1000'}
```

the code:

```
def openTempDic(self,loadfile, dicList):
    try:
        dicList.clear()
        path = '/Users/kunalmatharu/Desktop/reuters/temp/'
        f = open(path+loadfile, 'rb')
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        for row in reader:
            print row
            dicList[row['term']] = row['docID']
            print dicList[row['term']]
            print row['term']
        return dicList
    finally:
        f.close
```

Answer (score 1):

Python `dict`s are unordered hash tables. That is to say, items come out in some order when you print the dictionary, but this may not be the order in which they were inserted. If you want to maintain the order in which items were added, use `collections.OrderedDict`.

Comment: it doesnt wok on the list either??